# How to implement a simple Id-Generator?

Tags: f#

I have:

```
type Id = Id of int
let mutable IdInt = 0

let idGenerator = 
    fun _ ->
        IdInt <-  IdInt + 1
        IdInt |> Id
```

which is then called like e.g:

```
 printfn "%A" (idGenerator())
```

What's best practice to generate simple, incremental Ids in F#?

Comment: I have to disagree about putting this question on hold. Answers to this question will _not_ tend to be almost entirely based on opinions. The given answer is exactly what we would expect, is a common learning excersize for F# newcomers, and is frequently googled for. I suggest the question be released.

Comment: Maybe I should change the headline to "How to implement a **simple** ID-Generator"? Scott Wlaschin says, as beginner you should stay away from mutables. Well, I wasn't able to generate Ids without "mutable" involved. I have messed around with Seq.initInfinite  as well, but no success. So I just wasn't sure if I need the "mutable" stuff or if there is a much more functional solution to this problem. If there are other opinions: show me, please.

Comment: Well, Scott Wlashin's advice is good, but there seems to be exceptions to just about anything and everything in the digital world. Tomas Petricek's answer shows how you hide the mutable from the outside world. The implementation is so simple that we can clearly see there won't be a problem with that mutable. Keep shying mutables, but not at any cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your implementation is pretty much what I would do. There are two things that I'd change:

- Define the argument of the inline function as unit so that there is no confusion about its type
- Keep the mutable `IdInt`  variable local to the `idGenerator` so that it's hidden (and you can also use more idiomatic `camelCase` naming for it)

So, my slightly modified version would be:

```
let idGenerator = 
    let mutable idInt = 0
    fun () ->
        idInt <-  idInt + 1
        idInt |> Id
```

In some cases, it is also useful to make this a function that creates new generators (in case you want to have more local generators rather than one global):

```
let makeIdGenerator () = 
    let mutable idInt = 0
    fun () ->
        idInt <-  idInt + 1
        idInt |> Id

let idGen1 = makeIdGenerator ()
let idGen2 = makeIdGenerator ()
```

The two generators will independently generate IDs starting from 1. They are independent, because the `idInt` variable is now local, so it's not shared by the two generators.